# Parsing data quicker in Ubuntu than Windows 10

Tags: c++, parsing, fstream

I'm streaming and parsing data from a .txt file (100 MB - 4 GB) into a vector. Parsing data in Ubuntu 19.04 is much quicker than parsing that data in Windows 10. What could I do to speed up the parsing process in Windows?

I've tested the streaming speeds using std::getline in both OS's and the streaming speeds are similar. I've posted on a separate website http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/254030/ (I thought the issue was with the filesystems) but I've learned that it's more due to parsing the data in some way. I'm not sure of any other means to parse data than using the operators in the code.
Here is the code I've used for parsing the data to test times with both Windows and Ubuntu:

```
unsigned int date, time, mil;
double last, bid, ask;
unsigned int volume;
char delim;
int lineCount{0};

if (dataFile.is_open())
{
    while (dataFile >> date >> time >> mil >> delim >> last >> delim >> 
           bid >> delim >> ask >> delim >> volume)
    {
        lineCount++;
    }
}
```

Here is the code I used to read the files to test speeds with both Windows and Ubuntu:

```
int lineCount{0};
string line;

while (getline(dataFile, line))
{
    lineCount++;
}
```

Here are the results for both tests on each OS:

```
Ubuntu 19.04 with parsing:
execution time : 1.352 s

Windows 10 with parsing:
execution time : 27.474 s

Ubuntu 19.04 without parsing (just reading file):
execution time : 0.059 s

Windows 10 without parsing (just reading file):
execution time : 0.922 s
```

I thought both Linux and Windows would perform similarly, but they've extremely different results. The file I used for testing is only 64.9 MB

Comment: Did you try using `reserve()` to preallocate the vector?

Comment: Various different data structures have difference performances (most notably, unordered-map) due to things like allocation growth (often, it doubles at each iteration, however, this can suboptimal in certain cases), array size for a deque, the hashing algorithm for an unordered-map (MurmurHashUnaligned2 for GCC, FNV-1a for MSVC until recently, I forget what the recent hash algorithm is). Assuming the performance of all the containers is identical for different compilers is not necessarily a good one, since it may reflect different design choices. Anyway, pre-allocate your vector.

Comment: Even without adding elements to the vector, or removing it entirely, it parses much faster in Linux than in Windows. It doesn't affect the speed, at least noticeably.

Comment: Do you have optimizations enabled? Did you try profiling your code?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm not sure how to do that, but I will try and find out

Comment: There may be several reasons for Windows being slower than Linux (this has been true for ever). Specially when file reading from HDD, the antivirus and the big difference between `fat` or `ntfs` (Windows) and `ext4` (Linux) disk formats.

Comment: If you didn't optimize your code, @ZacharyLocklear, that would be a huge explanation for why. Windows vectors use fairly expensive debugging iterators to ensure there are no invalid comparisons done, which means debug builds are quite slow. In release builds, they're effectively pointers.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh, I've updated the question so that vectors aren't the issue. Even without the vector and just parsing the data, Windows is extremely slow compared to Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to answer your question without having the results of the profiler and how you did compile.

For example, if your run the program on MSVS 19 in debug mode, it will be extremely slow. If you run it in release mode, with all optimizations enabled, then it will be dramatically faster.

Then, next step. Run the profiler. It tells you, where the program is slow. It is not neccessarily the parsing, it is most liekely the reading.

And reading from a file can be dramatically sped up by using a bigger buffer. And then, you should also initialize the vectors size and reserve-size.

And use `emplace_back` and not `push_back`.

Please try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>


struct Data
{
    unsigned int date, time, mil;
    double last, bid, ask;
    unsigned int volume;
};

int main()
{
    // Create a vector with an big initial size
    std::vector<Data> fullData(10000);
    // If reallocation is neccessary, then use big data
    fullData.reserve(20000);


    // Variables to read
    unsigned int date{}, time{}, mil{};
    double last{}, bid{}, ask{};
    unsigned int volume{};
    char delim{};


    std::ifstream dataFile;
    // Big buffer for reading
    char buf[100000];
    // Set a big input buffer
    dataFile.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, sizeof buf);

    dataFile.open("yourFile.dat");
    if (dataFile.is_open())
    {
        while (dataFile >> date >> time >> mil >> delim >> last >> delim >>
            bid >> delim >> ask >> delim >> volume)
        {
            fullData.emplace_back(Data{ date, time, mil, last, bid, ask, volume });
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would be really interested, if this is still slow . . .

Comment: I tried the code. The results are the same/very similar. I've done multiple tests and it's not an issue with the vector. I'm only looking for reasons that it parses much slower in Windows. I've updated my question to be more specific with the problem. Thanks for the help. I hope you can continue.